# Anchor hash in Razor ASP.NET web pages

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, razor

I use ASP.NET core Web application (web pages) .NET core version 2.1. In the razor page, I have a link to a specific div element on another site (in the same project), like so:

```
<a href="/MyAspPage#idOfDiv">Link</a>
```

However, the Intellisense complains (and rightfully so), that there is no `/MyAspPage` in `wwwroot`. After the build, this works just fine, because the link is valid of course.

Is there a way to use the `asp-page` tag helper or any other tag helper to link to a hash anchor on another site? Such as (following does not work of course):

```
<a asp-page="/MyAspPage" asp-anchor="idOfDiv">Link</a>
```

**Edit:** What I want is a tag helper which would produce the exact link as above when I used the `href`. The link is valid and works after build because the application takes care of it.

Answer (score 7):

Are you looking for named anchors like this?

```
<a asp-controller="Foo" asp-action="Index" asp-fragment="bar">Features</a>
```

result:

```
https://localhost/Foo/Index#bar
```