# Add #something to the end of Html.ActionLink or Url.ActionLink

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor, actionlink

I want to generate a url like "http://localhost:20990/Plugins/StaticCodeErrorDefinition#arrayDereferenceAfterCheck".
Tried for something but all did not work.

Any help? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Found something here: [Anchor hash in Razor ASP.NET web pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51781021/anchor-hash-in-razor-asp-net-web-pages)

So the name of the # is "anchor hash". I checked "hass tag" before.

The answer is the asp helper:

```
<a asp-controller="Foo" asp-action="Index" asp-fragment="yourAnchorHash">Features</a>
```